# How would I go about extracting specific values from a curl request into arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, curl

I have a variable "s" that stores the output of the curl request.
My code is as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    std::string s;
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "www.ecobliss.co.za/run_student_query.php?query=Select%20*%20FROM%20data%20WHERE%20ID%20%3C%2030");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &s);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
   
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the request is as follows:

```
<p>Results from your query:</p><br>{"ID":"26","datetime":"2022-03-13 03:21:07","temperature":"25.3","humidity":"80.9","pressure":"1020.2"}<br>{"ID":"27","datetime":"2022-03-13 05:12:47","temperature":"24.8","humidity":"82.1","pressure":"1020.5"}<br>{"ID":"28","datetime":"2022-03-13 05:29:05","temperature":"24.9","humidity":"83.6","pressure":"1020.5"}<br>{"ID":"29","datetime":"2022-03-13 05:29:07","temperature":"24.9","humidity":"83.8","pressure":"1020.5"}
```

How would I go about putting the values of temperature, humidity and pressure into 3 different arrays?

Comment: You need to strip off the HTML and keep the JSON (rather trivial if the result is exactly as shown). Then there's many fine JSON libraries which can be used to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the task into the two pieces: 1) extract json parts by searching the 
 delimiter, 2) parse each json with any open json lib. Personally I prefer the one included in Wt library but there are many.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how to do this, I have never worked with JSON before.